# Highcharts chart.renderer.images not lining up with platbands

Tags: image, charts, highcharts, renderer

I am adding images using chart.renderer.image. I would like the images to line up with the beginning of each plotBand. I have the plotBand from position in axis units. However when I call toValue the images do not line up.

https://jsfiddle.net/uxeL76a9/23/

```
  for (var i = 0; i < plotBands.length; ++i) {
  var artist = plotBands[i];
  var xPos = chart.xAxis[0].toValue(artist['from'], true);
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your chart is inverted, so axes are swapped, and you have small mess with `toValue()`, see fixed code:

```
 var xPos = chart.xAxis[0].toValue(artist['from'], true);
```

Should be:

```
var xPos = chart.yAxis[0].toPixels(artist.from);
```

Working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/uxeL76a9/40/